# How to find the side lengths of a triangle in the incircle of a Pythagorean triple

Tags: algebra-precalculus, triangles, pythagorean-triples, triangle-centres

Given a Pythagorean triple with an incircle, how do I find the sides of a triangle connecting the triple's tangents to that incircle. In the diagram below, I know how to find side $\,i\,$ but not the other two.

How do I find point $\,H\,$ coordinates or is there some other way to find the lengths of segments $\,j\,$ and $\,k$?

[image]

$\textbf{Update: }$ From a comment by Calvin Lin, I have inferred that, if we let vertex circle radii moving counterclockwise from the upper right be
$\quad r_1=5\quad r_2=12\quad r_3=3\quad$ we can get the $H$-values as follows.

\begin{align*}
X_H =\dfrac{r_2}{r_1+r_2}\cdot(r_2+r_3)
=\dfrac{A(A-B+C)}{2C}
=\dfrac{180}{17}
\\\\Y_H 
=\dfrac{r_2}{r_1+r_2}\cdot(r_1+r_3)
=\dfrac{B(A-B+C)}{2 C}=\dfrac{96}{17}
\end{align*}
so

\begin{align*}
i&=\sqrt{(15-12)^2+(3-0)^2}=3\sqrt{2}\\
\\
j&=\sqrt{\bigg(12-\dfrac{180}{17}\bigg)^2+\bigg(\dfrac{96}{17}-0\bigg)^2}
=\dfrac{24}{\sqrt{17}}\\
\\
k&=\sqrt{\bigg(15-\dfrac{180}{17}\bigg)^2+\bigg(\dfrac{96}{17}-3\bigg)^2}
=15\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{17}}
\end{align*}

Thank you Calvin Lin.

Comment: The lengths of the tangents is well known in terms of $a, b, c$, so coordinates of $H$ can be easily obtained via a ratio of lengths.

Comment: Your drawing is wrong: as you might know, when you draw a triangle, based on two points of a diameter of a circle and some random point on the circle, that random point will have an angle of $\frac{\pi}{2}$. This also goes into the other direction: if you draw a circle through the three points of a rectangular triangle, then the hypothenusa is a diameter of that circle $\implies$ the centre of that circle is located on that hypothenusa. So, on your image: the centre of that circle **must be** located on $j$.

Comment: @Dominique The triangle in the incircle is not a right triangle and side $\,j\,$ is not a diameter. The triangle joins tangents of the incircle and no two of these tangents are ends of a diameter.

Comment: @poetasis: I believed the question was about a Pythagorean triple (like $3$, $4$, $5$), so a triangle gets constructed, having lines with lengths $3$, $4$ and $5$. Is that not what it all starts with?

Comment: @Dominique Yes, and $\,(3,4,5)\,$ might have been a better triple to show in this question. The two answers so far have provided correct values (though not for the same sides as mine) but I need to study the methods more to decide which, if either, to check as correct. I would also love an answer that takes advantage or any heuristics that might made available by a right angle and integer sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

With $(m,n)$ integers, and $m>n$ then $a = m^2-n^2, b = 2mn, c = m^2+n^2$ form a $Pyhagorean triple.$

For the $(15,8,17)$ triangle $m=4, n=1$

The perimeter of this triangle is
$p = a+b+c = m^2 - n^2 + 2mn + m^2+n^2 = 2m(m + n)\\
s = \frac 12 p = m(m+n)\\
r = \frac {ab}{p} = \frac {(m^2-n^2)(2mn)}{2m(m+n)} = n(m-n)\\
s-a = m(m+n)-m^2+n^2 = n(m+n)\\
s-b = m(m+n) - 2mn = m(m-n)$

$r$ is the radius of the in-circle if that was not clear.

$\tan \frac 12 A = \frac {r}{s-a} = \frac {n(m-n)}{n(m+n)} = \frac {m-n}{n+m}\\
\tan \frac 12 B = \frac {r}{s-b} = \frac {n(m-n)}{m(m-n)} = \frac {n}{m}$

$j = 2(s-a) \sin \frac 12 A = \frac {2n(m+n)(m-n)}{\sqrt {(m-n)^2 + (n+m)^2}} = \frac {2n(m^2-n^2)}{\sqrt {2m^2 + 2n^2}} = \frac {an\sqrt 2}{\sqrt{c}}$

$k = 2(s-b) \sin \frac 12 B = \frac {2mn(m-n)}{\sqrt {m^2 + n^2}} = \frac {b(m-n)}{\sqrt{c}}$

$i = (s-c)\sqrt 2 = n(m-n)\sqrt{2}$

With the $(15,8,17)$ triangle, $(i,j,k) = (3\sqrt 2, \frac {15\sqrt 2}{\sqrt {17}},\frac {24}{\sqrt {17}})$

Comment: You gave correct answer but I will have to study the approach. I have gotten use to favoring my own formula which is a variation of Euclid's formula that you are using.  
\begin{align*}
&A=(2n-1+k)^2-k^2&&=(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k\\ 
&B=2(2n-1+k)k    &&=\phantom{(2n-1)^2+{}} 2(2n-1)k+2k^2\\ 
&C=(2n-1+k)^2+k^2 &&=(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k+2k^2
\end{align*}

Comment: I arrived at the same inradius formula by a different route. Each vertex circle radius is a combination of the three sides with side opposite the vertex being subtracted. The right angle circle radius is the same as the incircle radius... $r = \dfrac{A+B-C}{2}= \dfrac{(m^2-n^2)+(2mn)- (m^2+n^2)}{2}=n(m-n)$

Comment: I have been able to follow all but the introduction of  
 $\,\sin\frac{1}{2} ()\,$ and what part of the RHS it is. The final formula is correct but I missed something in getting there.

Comment: $\triangle IAK$ isosceles.  $\overline {AO}$ perpendicularly bisects $\overline {IK}.$  The length of $\overline {IK}$ which I call $j$ because it is opposite $J$ has length $2(s-a)\sin \frac 12 A$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

For a general $\triangle ABC$, define the side lengths $BC = a$, $CA = b$, $AB = c$, the semiperimeter $s = (a+b+c)/2$, and the inradius $IA' = IB' = IC' = r$.

Then since $AB' = AC'$ and $BC' = BA'$ and $CA' = CB'$, we have $s = AB' + BC' + CA' = AC' = BA' + CB'$.  Moreover,
$$AB' = s - (BC' + CA') = s - (BA' + CA') = s - a,$$
so similarly,
$$BC' = s-b, \quad CA' = s-c.$$
Then since $\triangle AB'I \sim \triangle AA''B'$, it follows that
$$\frac{A''B'}{B'I} = \frac{AA''}{AB'}.$$
And since $\triangle AA''B'$ is right, $AA'' = \sqrt{(AB')^2 - (A''B')^2}$.  Hence
$$\frac{A''B'}{r} = \frac{\sqrt{(s-a)^2 - (A''B')^2}}{s-a},$$
and solving for $A''B'$ yields
$$A''B' = \frac{r(s-a)}{\sqrt{r^2 + (s-a)^2}}.$$

Since Heron's formula gives
$$|\triangle ABC| = \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$$
and we also have
$$|\triangle ABC| = |\triangle IAB| + |\triangle IBC| + |\triangle ICA| = \frac{rc + ra + rb}{2} = rs,$$
then
$$r = \sqrt{\frac{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}{s}}.$$  Consequently, after elimination of $r$ and simplification,
$$B'C' = 2A''B' = 2(s-a)\sqrt{\frac{(s-b)(s-c)}{bc}}.$$
Similarly, $$A'B' = 2(s-c)\sqrt{\frac{(s-a)(s-b)}{ab}}, \quad C'A' = 2(s-b)\sqrt{\frac{(s-c)(s-a)}{ca}}.$$
These formulae do not require $\triangle ABC$ to be right, nor that $a,b,c$ are integers.  However, if $\angle C$ is right, then some simplification occurs because $s-c = r$.  In particular,
$$A'B' = \frac{a+b-c}{\sqrt{2}}, \\
B'C' = (b+c-a)\sqrt{\frac{c-b}{2c}}, \\
C'A' = (a+c-b)\sqrt{\frac{c-a}{2c}}.
$$

Comment: $i=4.24\quad  j=5.82\quad   k=5.14\quad$ so your last equations yield the correct answers but not for the correct sides. I will study your approach. I did learn something already – that a semi-perimeter can be the sum of vertex circle radii and do not have to be the sum of half-side lines.

Comment: @poetasis My diagram labeling is not the same as yours, and the orientation of the right triangle is not the same.  You will need to take this into account.

Comment: your labelling still disagrees with your equations.  For example $\quad\dfrac{a+b-c}{\sqrt{2}}=3\sqrt{2}\approx 4.24 =CA'$

Comment: You provided correct values in the end but, with your drawing not to scale, I am not sure of your logic. A Pythagorean triple is a right triangle with integer sides and I would also like to work with any heuristics that that affords.

Comment: @poetasis **the right angle is at C**, which is what I said in my answer.  I don't know why you think this is wrong.

Comment: I would like to see an answer with a Pythagorean triple drawn to scale. That's a lot to ask but user317176 did so and it would make it easier to understand.  Perhaps you could also skip the steps you took to accommodate non-right triangles.  I do not know which these are because I'm not versed in much beyond Pythagorean triples.